# program into search

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

again this is a wordpress question.Thanks in advance.
**My goal**:
1,request url : localhost/search_encoded_searh_words.html 
2,mod rewrite to:localhost/search.php?s=encoded_search_words
3,*search.php* is my create file,just like index.php with one more line at the beginning. $_GET['s']=decode($_GET['s'])
**Problems**
wordpress judge this is a page file request not search request,title shows **Page not found** 
**in brief**
I want to search after decoding the search words
Any work around?

**My trick**:
in *search.php* modify the REQUEST_URI to localhost/?s=decoded_search_words

Answer (score 0):

try to rewrite the url to `localhost/index.php?s=encoded_search_words`,
then in search.php you need to get the query string from `$query_string` the query_string will  looks something like "s=search_key", you need to parse it and decode it. then use [`query_post`<sup>codex</sup>](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) to alter the query result like this.

```
query_posts( $args );

// The Loop
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    echo '<li>';
    the_title();
    echo '</li>';
endwhile;

// Reset Query
wp_reset_query();
```